# How to bring a stick to the ground using many people?

Tags: forces

The game is called "Helium Stick."

[image: Helium Stick]

The game involves a group of people facing each other on opposite sides of a long stick. People are holding the stick with one of their fingers from below.

The task: people need to lower the stick to the ground. But, this is interesting: they couldn't bring the stick down, because there is a rule that they cannot remove their finger from the stick.

It looks extreme easy. But in reality it's not. For some reason the stick just gets higher and higher. Why?

We tried it through half an hour and didn't succeed.

**Question:** Can someone PLEASE tell me, what is the solution for this group game?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without a more specific description of the mechanical process it is a question about human behavior. Can you make this more of a mechanics question?

Comment: @Daniel: I disagree.

Comment: I agree with @FabriceNEYRET. As he explains in his answer below, it's not human behaviour that's the key here.

Comment: I disagree with marking this question as off-topic. It's an interesting intersection of physics and game theory. Since this question is on hold, I'll put an answer in my next comment.

Comment: This activity is a test of trust and cooperation. If all the participants only concern themselves with keeping their finger on the tick, then they will keep firm contact with the stick and end up pushing it upwards from below. If the participants learn to trust each other, then they can keep only the bare minimum contact on the stick. This will leave at most two participants holding the weight of the stick. Whoever feels weight, slowly lowers their finger; everyone else just barely touches the stick, trusting the others to not push up. This is a bit like the prisoners' dilemma.

Comment: It seems to me that OPs interest is in solving the game and not in the physics behind it.

Answer (score 2):

If people are not exactly synchronous, the first person that wants to release the stick loses contact and thus can't. The problem is that people are not pushing (with just extra pressure if not succeeding in moving), but must "pull without attachment". So just by gravity it would keep balanced on all contact points only for no more that 2 people for a stick, 3 for a plate. However, with so many points (16 !) it's impossible. It can only go to the direction of the contact force, which is upward.

Comment: So basically, $F=ma$ and $F$ points upward if the people's hands touch the bottom of the stick.

Comment: Also note that this doesn't actually address the question: "Can someone PLEASE tell, what is the solution for this group work/game?" This post says that it's impossible. I doubt that, since I am able to put a stick on the ground using two fingers touching from opposite sides (just tried it), a sort of rough simulation of the group.

Comment: It's more complicated: people try to have F (pressure-weight) as small of possible, prefererably negative as long as not loosing contact.But it's already miraculous if they keep zero, and indeed the least unwanted motion of anybody, or the least pressure by doubt, yields a positive force.

Comment: Daniel's second remark: read my post up to the end. for 2 contacts it works. for more, especially 16, it's impossible.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it using eight of my fingers and a little cylindrical object. I had no problem. Obviously the fact that my eight fingers worked together is important, but I'd hardly say this is impossible.

Comment: I do not understand why "people try to have $F$ as small as possible". What do you mean when you say they try to have $F$ negative, i.e. what's your direction reference? Why can't the people move their fingers to the sides of the stick and maintain contact with lateral force?

Comment: It's not *mathematically* impossible. In particular I guess that if it's a trained theater group, and maybe with conduction of some music, thanks to the small elasticity of finger flesh, they might succeed. Note that been face to face suppose to kneel and change posture, which makes thing even harder for synchrony.

Comment: @DanielSank When you perform it by yourself its easy to move all your fingers down at the exact same time and speed. When separate people are doing it, one person moves down hoping the others will follow at the same speed but will probably lose contact as nobody else is expecting the motion. Losing contact means the rules are broken. As Fabrice says, you'd have to have almost impossible synchronization in order for everyone to move down in unison at the same exact speed and at the same exact time. The problem gets more diffcult with more people.

Comment: @SirajRKhan I think a force diagram showing what happens as some participants try to move their point of contact would be a good answer to this question.

Comment: Instructions make contact points settled all along the stick, not at the extremes (BTW people are facing and interweaved, so not so easy to try to trick as you suggest :-) ) . In my notation F is pressure (up) - weight force (down), + for up.